# Confuse about array and object in node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

I have a array for store object, which have an object in it already:

```
var obj = [{
    name: 'json',
    lang: 'en'
}];

console,.log(obj) //the result is OK;
```

then I want push another object into it, just like:

```
var newObj = {
    name: 'lee',
    lang: 'zh'
}

obj.push(newObj)
```

but after this I print the `obj` array,`console.log(obj)`, the result is `2` !!

Why this happen? How can I solve this problem?To store object in array correctly

Comment: The "obj" should be equivalent to `[{name: 'json', lang: 'en'},{name: 'lee', lang: 'zh'}]` after the described operations .. if not, that code is not a representative sample.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you didn't do `obj = obj.push(newObj);`, because `.push` method returns the number of elements after push; instead, the line should simply read `obj.push(newObj)`.

Comment: So how can I push data into array without push method?

Comment: @hh54188 Just do `obj.push(newObj);`.